# In a tournament if you walk away from the table when "all in" did you "abandon" your hand?

Tags: tournament, all-in, hand

In a tournament a player went all in.  Stated I am going to throw this away and walked 10 feet to the trash can and came back.  The other player stated hand abandonment his hand is dead.  As the "house" I ruled his hand is live and he wins the pot.

I have seen in the WSOP players all-in walk all over and no one has an issue.  So was I correct?  What is hand abandonment?

Answer (score 7):

"A hand may be considered and mucked if player is not at his seat" - WSOP rules. This is hand abandonment. "At his seat" is defined as touching or in reach of one's seat. However, this rule only applies in a situation where your hand can be mucked.

It is not possible to fold when you are all-in for a variety of reasons, not the least of which is it would make collusion quite easy and there is never a reason to fold all-in. Due to this rule, a player cannot abandon his all-in hand as they do not have the option to fold. You were correct. Good job!

Comment: 100% correct. Hand cannot be dead if a player's tournament life is at risk. +1